# read.transactions in R resulting in line appears to contain an embedded null

Tags: r, syntax-error, apriori, arules, market-basket-analysis

Using the attached dataset in RStudio, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in readLines(file, encoding = encoding) : 
 (converted from warning) line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
```

After the following code:

```
txn = read.transactions(file="ItemList22.xlsx", rm.duplicates=TRUE, format="basket",sep=",",cols=1,quote = "\"'", skip = 0,encoding="unknown");
```

I'm trying to set the data up for Apriori analysis using the 'arules' package.  Per other StackOverflow posts and CRAN documentation, I've tried adding encoding options to the above code... but they don't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's the R code:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!An5uX7zzGqFNab9zBYiiMIUv0IQ

Comment: Here's the data source:  https://1drv.ms/x/s!An5uX7zzGqFNageb0n0_Gjz_RLg

Comment: You are trying to load a Microsoft Excel (xlsx) file, whereas `read.transactions` appears to expect a delimited text file.  You will need to export the Excel file as a delimited text file.

Comment: would agree with Eric. read.transactions is reading text file, not xlsx file.

Comment: I get a new error message when I bring in a text file.